# unexpected output, confusion between float and integer

Tags: java, math, floating-point

I have two statements in java:

`System.out.println(2 * (5 / 2 + 5 / 2 ));`

This generate the output `8` but again in next line:

`System.out.println(2 * 5 / 2 + 2 * 5 / 2 );`

This generate the output `10`.

now my confusion is why it generates different output

please someone describe it. thanks

Comment: you execute two different statements and you are confused you get a different output? why? forget about programming, think maths and order of executions. try to calculate and check why it is different

Comment: There's no floats. You're doing integer division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that division between `int`s generates an `int` (rounded down).

```
2 * (5 / 2 + 5 / 2) => 2 * (2 + 2) => 8

2 * 5 / 2 + 2 * 5 / 2 => 10 / 2 + 10 / 2 => 10
```

To get the exact value, you would have to use `float`s:

```
2 * (5.0 / 2 + 5.0 / 2) == 10
```

Comment: according to `bodmas` rule, divide get execute first, I thought it should be
`2 * 5 / 2 + 2 * 5 / 2 => 2*2 + 2*2 => 8`